# why does socket.io error 500 with express.io?

Tags: socket.io

Why does socket.io now give 500 (Internal Server Error) with express.io??

client side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("http://www.mysite.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js",function(){
        var socket = io.connect('http://www.mysite.com:8000'); //<<--error
        socket.emit('ready'); 
        });});
```

server side:

```
var express = require('express.io')
  , engine = express().http().io();

engine.use(express.cookieParser());
engine.use(express.session({secret:'monkey'}));
engine.all('/',function(req,res,next){res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With");next();});
engine.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.loginDate = new Date().toString()
    res.sendfile(__dirname)
    });


engine.listen(8000);


engine.io.route('ready',function(socket){console.log('hellooooooooooo');});
```

I am following the docs on https://github.com/techpines/express.io, I have only changed two things: cross domain and app is called engine instead. I just can't see the problem Has anyone else got this to work?

Note: it's not using express.js it's using express.io (more compatable with socket.io)

It's like socket.io is not their listening on the server even though engine = express().http().io(); io is socket.io

Comment: Is the socket.io server different from your regular http server.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, but I fixed it by copying and pasting the code sample in express.io sample code, and it worked. Then I compared them to check what the problem could be and observed that order of the code matters.

This order results in an error:

> - **static**
> - **cookieParser**
> - **session**

But when I followed the code provided in the sample code, I found out that this order works:

> - **cookieParser**
> - **session**
> - **static**

Hopefully this will also help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the posted example is failing because you're using the call `res.sendfile(__dirname)` without supplying a filename.

This is coming from express.io, notice it uses `res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html')`:

```
express = require('express.io')
app = express().http().io()

// Setup your sessions, just like normal.
app.use(express.cookieParser())
app.use(express.session({secret: 'monkey'}))

// Session is automatically setup on initial request.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.session.loginDate = new Date().toString()
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html')
})
```

Comment: The first answer is incorrect. The order of express middleware is important, for instance `express.cookieParser()` needs to come before `express.session()` because the session code depends on the connect.sid cookie. 

The `express.static` middleware though does not depend on cookies/sessions and can come before or after.